# Populating JSON listview in a fragment with volley

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I am a green horn in java/android programming but I was trying to add different tutorials to create a customized application that would be a cool experiment, this could be something very easy to most of the people here but am stuck in this one and I am trying to use this [Navigation Drawer View Pager](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) trying to populate the tab one fragment with this [Custom ListView with Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/).from android hive "great tutorials btw".

I want to transfer the code in the **MainActivity.java** of custom listview with volley to a **HomeFragment.java** in navigation drawer but I get errors.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  // Log tag
   private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// Movies json url
private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // changing action bar color
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>         ();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                      }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
 }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**HomeFragment**

```
  public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
    }
```

**Combined Code**

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
//private TextView txtFragmentone;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        //txtFragmentone = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtFragmentOne);
        //txtFragmentone.setText(R.string.fragment_tab_one);
        rootView.setLayoutParams(new        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));

        listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // changing action bar color
        getActivity().getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#4cbaff")));

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                        .doubleValue());
                                movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                                // Genre is json array
                                JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }



    }
```

However I an error at

```
rootView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,      LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));
```

**AppController.java**

```
  package androidhive.info.materialdesign.app;

   import com.android.volley.Request;
   import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
   import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
   import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
   import androidhive.info.materialdesign.util.LruBitmapCache;

   import android.app.Application;
   import android.text.TextUtils;

    /**
    * @author fanjavaid
    *
    */
  public class AppController extends Application {
    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
  }
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="androidhive.info.materialdesign.activity.HomeFragment">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However if i change `LayoutParams` to `Linear.LayoutParams` it crashes
If you could help it would be awesome !!!

Comment: It's very difficult as a beginner to get everything working all at once.  I recommend starting with just one very simple thing - an activity with a ListView that displays static content.  Then get the Volley code working retrieving the data you need in the format you need.  Then populate the ListView dynamically from the Volley data, and so on.  The job will be easier, and if you get stuck you'll have an easier time getting help because you can ask a narrowly focused question rather than this monster with tons of code nobody wants to read.

Comment: I have same issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780259/custom-adapter-in-fragment-with-get-json-value/42780456#42780456), may be someone can help us! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to achieve the same.
I combined the login and the navigation drawer.
I also tried to display in home fragment a static data and it worked .
For debugging purpose i changed the default fragment to the 2nd fragment.
So now when i open the drawer, and click on the home tab, I again go back to the login screen.