# Custom Adapter in fragment with get json value

Tags: android, json, xml, android-fragments

I'm trying to get list from JSON in fragment when show the fragment in activity. 
I have problem when I will show the adapter.

**SiswaFragment**

```
public class SiswaFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private List<MenuItem> menuItem;
    private ListView listView;
    private MenuListAdapter listAdapter;
    private String URL_FEED = AppConfig.URL;


    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public SiswaFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static SiswaFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        SiswaFragment fragment = new SiswaFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_siswa, container, false);
        //session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listSiswa);
        menuItem = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        String no_hp = "085733777717";
        String URL = URL_FEED + "/?nomor_hp=" + no_hp;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Do something with the response

                        try{

                            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray feedArray = o.getJSONArray("data");

                            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), feedObj.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
                                item.setId(feedObj.getString("kode"));
                                item.setImage(AppConfig.URL_ASSETS + "user.png");
                                item.setName(feedObj.getString("nama"));
                                item.setDescription(feedObj.getString("kelas"));
                                item.setRemarks(feedObj.getString("sekolah"));

                                menuItem.add(item);
                            }

                            //txt.setText(sb.toString());


                        }  catch (JSONException ex){}

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Handle error
                    }
                });

        listAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(getActivity(), menuItem);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rq.add(stringRequest );
        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

**MenuListAdapter**

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<MenuItem> menuItem;
    private SessionManager session;
    private Database db;
    private Context context;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public MenuListAdapter(Activity activity, List<MenuItem> menuItem) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.menuItem = menuItem;
        this.context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return menuItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return menuItem.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        db = new Database(activity.getApplicationContext());

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(activity.getApplicationContext());

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null);
        }

        if (imageLoader == null) {
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        }

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        //FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

        final MenuItem item = menuItem.get(position);

        name.setText(item.getName());
        description.setText(item.getDescription());
        image.setImageUrl(item.getImage(), imageLoader);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I found problem when this running and just showing the blink (force close). I think the issue at `listAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(getActivity(), menuItem);` and `listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);`.
Hope I was clear, thanks.

Comment: at first add `listAdapter = new MenuListAdapter..` above catch block `here //txt.setText` and show error code

Comment: does it crash ?

Comment: Still the same.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is fine except one thing...!

You have set the adapter just before your request and that time your menu list is empty because you haven't received any data from bac-kend.

```
//just here
listAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(getActivity(), menuItem);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rq.add(stringRequest );
```

So, you will get data when `onResponse` callback will be invoked...
You can add a logic in it to just initialize your adapter before this and refresh your menu list and call `notifyDataSetChanged` method to refresh your listview.

Just modify your method like this:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_siswa, container, false);
    //session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listSiswa);
    menuItem = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    String no_hp = "085733777717";
    String URL = URL_FEED + "/?nomor_hp=" + no_hp;
    listAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(getActivity(), menuItem);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Do something with the response

                    try{

                        JSONObject o = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray feedArray = o.getJSONArray("data");

                        for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), feedObj.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
                            item.setId(feedObj.getString("kode"));
                            item.setImage(AppConfig.URL_ASSETS + "user.png");
                            item.setName(feedObj.getString("nama"));
                            item.setDescription(feedObj.getString("kelas"));
                            item.setRemarks(feedObj.getString("sekolah"));

                            menuItem.add(item);
                        }

                        //txt.setText(sb.toString());
                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }  catch (JSONException ex){}

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // Handle error
                }
            });
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rq.add(stringRequest );
    return view;
}
```

Comment: @Yohanes Budi Hartoyo if this my answer is helpful for you, please accept my answer.

Comment: Thanks about your help. But, my issue has not solved yet. Still the same with previous one.

Comment: 03-14 17:14:00.313    1342-3949/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity 1 com.absensi.studenttoparent/.activity.MainActivity

Comment: I got example from [http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/] for sliding menu and fragment, and combile with [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673159/parsing-json-from-url-with-volley-in-a-fragment-in-android] for function onCreateView.

logcat -->  `W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity 1 com.absensi.studenttoparent/.activity.MainActivity`

Comment: you can check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095746/populating-json-listview-in-a-fragment-with-volley), hope this will help.